# TCP Server crashes when client disconnects

Tags: c#, tcp

My TCP server will crash if my client ungracefully disconnects. The exception is occurring when reading from a created client in the TCPServer.

`unable to read data from the transport connection`

```
    public async void StartReadAsync() {
        while (await ReadAsync());
    }

    private async Task<bool> ReadAsync() {
        int amountRead = await stream.ReadAsync(readBuffer, 0, readBuffer.Length, cts.Token).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

I crash on the await stream.ReadAsync as soon as the client DCs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the instruction into a TRY-CATCH structure

```
try
{
    int amountRead = await stream.ReadAsync(readBuffer, 0, readBuffer.Length, cts.Token).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
catch
{
}
```

I´m not supposing you want to know the exception itself but just to avoid a crash in program. If you want, you may set CATCH to display which exception is being performed.

See more at:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/0yd65esw.aspx